# submenu disappears in orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, android-orientation

I have an android app that displays a menu item that when selected shows a sub-menu. When the device orientation is changed the sub-menu disappears?

I have read the related posts, but none of them actually deal with a sub-menu item. Do I use on "saved/on restore", somehow check to see if the sub-menu item is displayed and then somehow restore it? Use "on configuration change" and do the same thing?

Everything else displays fine with orientation changes except for the sub-menu items. If anyone has any ideas I would be glad to hear them. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd at least specify the OS you're working with...

Answer (score -1):

while you are desinging screen, you should desing scene according to landscape and portrait mode. In design part, try two mode and adjust proper design for landscape and portrait. so that if you are change the orientation your desing will be proper.

Comment: I have designed layouts for both landscape & portrait, that is not the issue.  The sub-menu that is displayed when an options-menu item is selected disappears when the orientation is changed, the layouts & everything else (data) are restored properly but the sub-menu closes/disappears. It can be reopened by opening the menu and re-selecting the menu item associated with the sub-menu. No other detrimental occurrences happen, like I said it is as if the sub-menu & the displayed choices are cancelled. Is a sub-menu suppose to persist through an orientation change??

Comment: because android destroys and then starts from beginnig this scene when you are change the orientation. before you change orientation, you should save scene activity. so look at this page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: In case anyone else has this problem- I wasn't able to find an answer to this question - I think sub-menu items are NOT suppose to persist with an orientation change, so I changed the sub-menus to activity's with a simple list view and solved the problem.